# Refering to a column name that is a number with a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a problem:
My table has some columns that are numbers. I can refer to them using [].
However, that doesn't work if I want to refer to a column using variable.

E.g. I declare a variable @i, set it to 1. How can I use it in order to refer to a column that's named '1'?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Usually you would only do this for dynamic SQL in which case it would just be `'[1]'`

Comment: I've got a table with columns that are months (e.g. 1-36).
For each @i (number of a month), I want to update a row with given value (sum of other rows, but number of these rows also depends on another variable), in the column that it refers to

Comment: To use a variable for a column name, you have to use dynamic sql.   So you just include the [] in your dynamic sql string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're looking for something like this to take an `int` used for looping and `convert` it to a string representation used to reference the column:

```
DECLARE @i AS INT = 1

SELECT '[' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), @i) + ']'
```

**Produces**: `[1]`

You could use this in a dynamic SQL statement like so:

```
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL('SELECT [' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), @i) + ']... FROM YOUR_TABLE')
```

Comment: I want to use that [30] in
update Table set '[' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), @i) + ']'=0
and that doesn't really work..

Comment: You need to build the *whole* SQL statement as a string, then EXEC() or sp_executeSQL it, you cannot randomly substitute filed names for variables